# Would 1.6.4 mods work in an 1.7.2 modpack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-technic-pack

I'm creating a modpack on the *Technic Launcher*, and I set the client to *1.7.2*

However, a few of the mods I downloaded only tout support for version *1.6.4*. will they still work in the launcher? Or is there a way of updating them or a *program/mod* that you put in with them to make it work?

I'm using Forge *1.7.2* as well.

Comment: In general, a mod will work unless it changed something in Minecraft that *itself* was changed in the latest update. I would say try it out one mod at a time and see how you go.

Comment: What about a mod that is 1.8? (does the mod work even if it doesn't use the items that are in 1.8 but not in 1.7.2?)

Comment: I don't think so no, Backwards compatibility is a 'maybe', I have doubts about forwards-compatibility. If it's a well known mod chances are there are older versions. Look for an 'older versions' section on the mod's page.

Answer (score 13):

To paraphrase Martin Sojka: **No**.

The reason is that, unlike what Timelord suggested, minecraft mods don't alter assets. Most mods for games take the existing level data, or textures, or data files and change them in small ways.

Minecraft mods on the other hand are entire pieces of new code that are run in the game, and while a game developer will keep the loading of data the same between versions (cause otherwise they'd have to do over all *their* work as well). With code you don't do that because there's no benefit as a developer, you don't change things for the sake of changing them but you generally don't care (much) about mods either.

1.7 especially made a really big change in preparation for 1.8: They did away with the primary method of looking up items. Where in old versions of minecraft you went "Give the player block id 1" to give them a stone, now it's "Give the player minecraft:stone".

Sources:

- Multipart tutorial on upgrading a 1.6 mod to 1.7:

  - http://www.wuppy29.com/minecraft/modding-tutorials/wuppys-minecraft-forge-modding-tutorials-for-1-7-updating-1-6-to-1-7-part-1-modfile-and-recipes/#sthash.ONDkbJxP.dpbs
- http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/mods-discussion/1407637-how-do-i-install-1-6-4-mods-on-1-7-2 and countless posts like it
- The amount of time it took for mods to get updated

Comment: +1, Thanks for taking the time to explain fully, It's good to know that 1.7.2 changed the lookup stuff so drastically. I can see where Martin was coming from now.

Answer (score 0):

Modifications to a game alter the way it behaves, but more specifically to the context of this question, it is doing so at the asset level.

You alter the files to get the expected modification.

If the new version of the original game alters any of the assets we are modifying, the modification will not behave as it did originally, and that is why out of date mods tend to have issues.

**I can personally vouch that this does not always make a difference**, however, **my experience comes from other games**.

**Martin Sojka** insists that 1.6.4 and 1.7.2 vary so greatly from each other that, if not for the nature of Minecraft, they would be given different titles.

If this is the case, minimalistic mods may still work, i.e. the ones that did not really do much to begin with. If they automated a few command lines, or changed an interface that is still there, that will likely still all work as intended. But any mod worth the time will likely cause issues, as it will effectively be talking a different dialect of the same language to Minecraft.

To answer your second question, the only way to get around any issues that come out would be to modify the modification to support the newer version. This is most likely not something you should do without a great amount of knowledge on what your doing.

My recommendation past that is to check the official site for the mod developers. Find out if they plan on releasing a newer version, and if not, maybe contact them and ask for an update. At the very least, they would have better knowledge of their own product to give you advice on using it in a newer version.

Comment: "Assets" are usually a term for graphics, models, levels, sounds, videos - almost everything that's not a code or a database. But you are right in the sense that mods change individual code files, and if that file wasn't touched by upgrade, a mod will likely (but still not surely) work.

Comment: Most of the time. In game developing, assets can refer to the code files or database structures, but this is likely specific to situations where they are treated as separate files.